# Building Chromium for Mac - aarch64-apple-darwin lib not found

Tags: xcode, rust, chromium, rust-cargo, chromium-os

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ESU.png)While building chromium in my local following this article - https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/docs/mac_build_instructions.md

I encountered this error while executing `autoninja -C out/Default chrome` command given in the instructions.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/gauravk/Documents/chromium/src/third_party/rust-toolchain/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib'
[21/38436] ACTION //components/flags_ui/resources:build_ts(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_arm64)
```

I am not sure how do I change something that is coming from chromium git itself, I mean the source code.

I tried installing Rust in my Mac.

```
> rustc --version 
rustc 1.71.1
```

Yeah, I do have `~/.cargo/bin` in the path.

Also, I saw this article https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82222, but I have already installed the latest Xcode 14 installed.

Also, I followed this article
https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2413#issuecomment-733998798 - still the same error

I FOUND THE SOLUTION :

It turns out that the python returns machine as x86-64 instead of arm64. So installing python 3.11 returns the correct machine.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1467374&q=rust%20in%20OS%3DMac&can=1

Comment: did you run `gclient sync` after syncing the source code?

Comment: I guess it already does that @Asesh. Added the screenshot.